# dynamic column order, hide/show in a table

Tags: blazor

Using 'typeparam' and 'RenderFragment' to create this table template in a component.
I have created a button to hide and show the description column with a Boolean inverting method. If I wanted this functionality for every column I would end up with 8 conditional statements for the header row and another 8 for each record in the dataset. Fine for a small dataset. But not efficient for a large table.

```cs
<button class="@(@hide_description == true ? "btn btn-sm btn-secondary"  : "btn btn-sm btn-primary")" 
onclick=@ToggleHideDescription > @(@hide_description == true? "Show" : "Hide") </button>
<MVCTable TItem=@SharedTestData data=@data>
    <HeaderRow>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            @if( @hide_description ){ }else{ <th scope="col">Description</th> }
            <th scope="col">Executed</th>
            <th scope="col">By</th>
            <th scope="col">Pass</th>
            <th scope="col">Error CF</th>
    </HeaderRow>
    <TableRow >
            <tr @key=context>
                <td scope="row">@context.id</td>
                <td >@context.name</td>
                @if( @hide_description ){ }else{ <td >@context.description</td> }
                <td >@context.executed_on</td>
                <td >@context.executed_by</td>
                <td >@context.success</td>
                <td >@context.error_CF</td>
            </tr>
    </TableRow>
</MVCTable>

@code {
    public bool hide_description { get; set; } = true;
    public void ToggleHideDescription()
    {
        hide_description = !hide_description;
    }
    public SharedTestData[] data = new SharedTestData[]
    {
        new SharedTestData(){ id="ET220301", name="Efficiency", description="test for efficiency of program", executed_by="RX1",executed_on= DateTime.Now, error_CF= 0.31M, success=true },
        new SharedTestData(){ id="ET220302", name="Concurrenc", description="test for ability to manage resources", executed_by="RX1",executed_on= DateTime.Now, error_CF= 0.21M, success=false },
        new SharedTestData(){ id="ET220303", name="Effability", description="test for ability eff with system", executed_by="RX1",executed_on= DateTime.Now, error_CF= 0M, success=false },
        new SharedTestData(){ id="ET220304", name="Edability", description="test for edibility", executed_by="RX1",executed_on= DateTime.Now, error_CF= 0.8M, success=true },
        new SharedTestData(){ id="ET220305", name="Efficiency", description="test for efficiency of program", executed_by="RX2",executed_on= DateTime.Now, error_CF= 0.31M, success=true },
        new SharedTestData(){ id="ET220306", name="Concurrenc", description="test for ability to manage resources", executed_by="RX2",executed_on= DateTime.Now, error_CF= 0.21M, success=false },
        new SharedTestData(){ id="ET220307", name="Effability", description="test for ability to eff with system", executed_by="RX2",executed_on= DateTime.Now, error_CF= 0M, success=false },
        new SharedTestData(){ id="ET220308", name="Edability", description="test for edibility", executed_by="RX2",executed_on= DateTime.Now, error_CF= 0.8M, success=true }
    };
}
```

**Solution Theory**

I think I would want to preload the 'tr' component layout somehow I imagine? But I have no idea how I could do that. I thought of populating an array with 'Func<RenderFragment,value>' But I don't know how to handle the varying value datatypes in a row.

Comment: Consider a state class per column. Create separate components that draw the button, th and td elements. These components should take the state class as a parameter. The td component could be generic or simply just display a `ChildContent` `RenderFragment`. You then have a choice use logic in the components to render not render the content or... filter a list of state classes and render columns via an iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated

Here's a fairly simplistic set of components and a demo using the Weather Forecasts `FetchData` to demonstrate some of the concepts you can use.

As you are trying to remove the column display logic from the render process and know about `RenderFragments`, I've updated the answer to show you how you can "pre-build" the Column Template so the logic only gets called once for each row.

##### `ListControl.razor`.

A fairly standard template control.

```
@typeparam TRecord

@if (this.IsLoaded)
{
    <table @attributes="this.SplatterAttributes">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @this.HeaderTemplate
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in this.Records!)
            {
                <tr @key=item>
                    @RowTemplate!(item)
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
else
{
    <div class="m-2 p-2">Loading...</div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] [EditorRequired] public bool IsLoaded { get; set; } = false;

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IDictionary<string, object> SplatterAttributes { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? HeaderTemplate { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TRecord>? RowTemplate { get; set; }

    [Parameter] [EditorRequired] public IEnumerable<TRecord>? Records { get; set; }
}
```

##### `ListColumnHeaderControl.razor`

```
<th @attributes=this.SplatterAttributes>
    @this.ChildContent
</th>

@code {
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IDictionary<string, object> SplatterAttributes { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

##### `ListColumnControl.razor`

```
    <td @attributes="this.SplatterAttributes">
        @this.ChildContent
    </td>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IDictionary<string, object> SplatterAttributes { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

And then used in `FetchData.razor`

```
@page "/fetchdata"

<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>

@using BlazorApp1.Data
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>
<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="ShowDateColumn">Show/Hide Date</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="ShowTempCColumn">Show/Hide Temp C</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="ShowTempFColumn">Show/Hide Temp F</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="ShowSummaryColumn">Show/Hide Summary</button>
</div>
<ListControl class="table" TRecord="WeatherForecast" IsLoaded=this.Loaded Records=this.forecasts HeaderTemplate=this.headerTemplate RowTemplate=this.rowTemplate />

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

    private bool dateColumn = true;
    private bool TempCColumn = true;
    private bool TempFColumn = true;
    private bool SummaryColumn = true;

    private bool Loaded = false;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Loaded = false;
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
        Loaded = true;
    }

    private void ShowDateColumn()
    {
        this.dateColumn = !this.dateColumn;
    }

    private void ShowTempCColumn()
    {
        this.TempCColumn = !this.TempCColumn;
    }

    private void ShowTempFColumn()
    {
        this.TempFColumn = !this.TempFColumn;
    }

    private void ShowSummaryColumn()
    {
        this.SummaryColumn = !this.SummaryColumn;
    }

    private RenderFragment<WeatherForecast> rowTemplate => context => __builder =>
    {
        if (this.dateColumn)
        {
            <ListColumnControl>@context.Date.ToShortDateString()</ListColumnControl>
        }
        if (this.TempCColumn)
        {
            <ListColumnControl>@context.TemperatureC</ListColumnControl>
        }
        if (this.TempFColumn)
        {
            <ListColumnControl>@context.TemperatureF</ListColumnControl>
        }
        if (this.SummaryColumn)
        {
            <ListColumnControl >@context.Summary</ListColumnControl>
        }
    };

    private RenderFragment headerTemplate => __builder =>
    {
        if (this.dateColumn)
        {
            <ListColumnHeaderControl>Date</ListColumnHeaderControl>
        }
        if (this.TempCColumn)
        {
            <ListColumnHeaderControl>Temp C</ListColumnHeaderControl>
        }
        if (this.TempFColumn)
        {
            <ListColumnHeaderControl>Temp F</ListColumnHeaderControl>
        }
        if (this.SummaryColumn)
        {
            <ListColumnHeaderControl>Summary</ListColumnHeaderControl>
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to add this example. 
But in your example ListColumnControl.razor '@if (this.Show)' and '@if (this.IsHeader)' will be executed on every field of every row no?

Comment: In a theoretical situation where you are conditionally rendering from so many hundreds of thousands of data items that `if` statements start having real-word effects on time, you will have potentially so many rows rendered in the browser that it will explode.  Do you have any idea how many basic comparisons even a cheap mobile device can do?

Comment: I understand that, but I am in a situation where I have to create a editable table where the data class has +50 columns and rows will span up to 200 with pagination. I also plan to implement column orderering at a later stage. So I would prefer to run just 50 conditions rather than 50 x 200

Comment: I'd be surprised if 1000 conditional checks added a hundredth of a millisecond to the execution time on the page.  Is this really what you want to spend your new-to-Blazor time on?

Comment: As your wish is to refine the logic to only execute as little as possible, I've updated my answer to show how to build the RowTemplate `RenderFragment`.  The code logic only gets called once for each row now.  It demonstrates a slightly different approach to your posted answer.  However, I agree with @Bennyboy1973 that I don't think the old way will have a significant impact on performance.  The `Editable` and `Column Sorting` will add a lot more logic!

Comment: Thank you for your Example MrC. I had not yet noticed your update until after I updated my answer.

Comment: Shaun, what does the exclamation mark in `this.Records!` and `@RowTemplate!` mean?  I've never seen that before.  --edit-- just Googled it.  Why didn't I come across this in "what's new in C#" vids? :D

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 - you've found it.  In the new Nullable world you sometimes need a way of saying "Yes I know it's declared as a null but I've set it in `OnInitialized` or it's injected so can't be null, but the parser is too stupid to know it can't be null".

Answer (score 0):

I updated and cleaned up the solution a bit and added a bit more explanation. Should I change the title of my question to 'BLAZOR: dynamic templating with hide/reorder columns in a table'?

An integral part of this solution is the use of `RenderFragments` defined in code (see code in `TableTest.razor`). I found documentation on how to do that here [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-6.0#define-reusable-renderfragments-in-code). An Important side-note here is that

*Assignment to a RenderFragment delegate is only supported in Razor component files (.razor), and **event callbacks aren't supported**.*

Suggestions on how to overcome this issue would be appreciated.

**SharedTestData.cs** dataset for testing purposes

```cs
namespace BlazorTestSandbox.Client.Shared.DataClass
{
    public class SharedTestData
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public DateTime executed_on { get; set; }
        public string executed_by { get; set; }
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public decimal error_CF { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

**MVCColumnCtrl.cs** to be instantiated per column in the sample data dataset(`SharedTestData`)

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BlazorTestSandbox.Client.Shared.MVCTable
{
    public class MVCColumnCtrl<TItem>
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public bool visible { get; set; } = true;
        public RenderFragment<TItem> RenderValue { get; set; }
        public MVCColumnCtrl(
            string id, RenderFragment<TItem> RenderValue, string label = ""
        )
        {
            this.id = id;
            if (label == "")
            {
                this.label = id;
            } else { 
                this.label = label;
            }
            this.RenderValue = RenderValue;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**MVCTable.razor** iterates and renders data and columns, receives `MVCColumnCtrl` array and `SharedTestData` array from `TableTest.razor` page

```cs
@using BlazorTestSandbox.Client.Shared.AppStates
@using BlazorTestSandbox.Client.Shared
@using BlazorTestSandbox.Client.Shared.DataClass

@typeparam TItem

<table class="table  table-striped table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        @foreach(MVCColumnCtrl<TItem> Col in visible_col_names)
        {
            <th scope="col" >@Col.label</th>
        }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            @foreach (TItem item in data)
            {
                <tr>
                @foreach(MVCColumnCtrl<TItem> Col in visible_col_names)
                {
                    @Col.RenderValue(item)
                }
                </tr>
            }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TItem> data { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public MVCColumnCtrl<TItem>[] visible_col_names { get; set; }
}
```

---

**MVCTableColumnManager.razor** renders dropdown menu and adds column hiding and ordering functionality, receives `MVCColumnCtrl` array and `RefreshColumns` Action form `TableTest.razor` page

```cs
@typeparam TItem

<div 
    class=@(show? "dropdown show" : "dropdown" )
>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" 
  aria-expanded=@show
  @onclick=@(()=> @show = !@show )
  >⚙</button>
    <div class=@(show? "dropdown-menu show" : "dropdown-menu" )>
      <div class="px-4 py-3">
         <table class="table  table-striped table-sm">
           <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" >#</th>
                    <th scope="col" >Column</th>
                    <th scope="col" >Show</th>
                    <th scope="col" >Order</th>
                </tr>
          </thead>
            <tbody>
               @for (var i = 0; i < mvc_columns.Length ; i++)
               {
                    MVCColumnCtrl<TItem> Col = mvc_columns[i];
                    int row_i = i + 0;
                        <tr>
                    <td>@(row_i+1)</td>
                    <td scope="row" ><b>@Col.label</b> </td>
                    <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" @onchange=@(()=>ToggleVisibleCol(@Col) ) checked=@Col.visible  /></td>
                    <td>
                        <button @onclick=@(()=>MoveColUp(@Col, @row_i) ) class="btn-outline-primary pb-0 pt-0" style="border-radius: 3px!important">↑</button>
                        <button @onclick=@(()=>MoveColDown(@Col, @row_i) ) class="btn-outline-primary pb-0 pt-0" style="border-radius: 3px!important">↓</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
               }
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
@code {
    private bool show  { get; set; } = false;
    [Parameter] public MVCColumnCtrl<TItem>[] mvc_columns { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Action RefreshColumns { get; set; }
    public void ToggleVisibleCol(MVCColumnCtrl<TItem> Col)
    {
        Col.visible = !Col.visible; 
        RefreshColumns();
    }
    public void MoveColUp(MVCColumnCtrl<TItem> colUp, int i)
    {
        int iUp = 0;
        MVCColumnCtrl<TItem> colDown = null;
        if(i != 0)
        {                    
            iUp = i - 1;
            colDown = mvc_columns[i - 1];
        }
      
        if(colDown != null && colUp != null)
        {            
            mvc_columns[iUp] = colUp;
            mvc_columns[iUp + 1] = colDown;
            RefreshColumns();
        }
    }
    public void MoveColDown(MVCColumnCtrl<TItem> colDown, int i)
    {
        int iDown = 0;
        MVCColumnCtrl<TItem> colUp = null;
        if(i !=  mvc_columns.Length-1)
        {                    
            iDown = i + 1;
            colUp = mvc_columns[i + 1];
        }
        if(colUp != null && colDown != null)
        {            
            mvc_columns[iDown] = colDown;
            mvc_columns[iDown - 1] = colUp;
            RefreshColumns();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**TableTest.razor** here all the models and data are instantiated and passed to components I `MVCTableColumnManager` and `MVCTable`. This should probably be cleaned up a bit

```cs
@page "/TableTest"
@using BlazorTestSandbox.Client.Shared.AppStates
@using BlazorTestSandbox.Client.Shared.DataClass
@using BlazorTestSandbox.Client.Shared.MVCTable
<h3>TableTest</h3>

<MVCTableColumnManager 
    TItem=@SharedTestData 
    mvc_columns=@mvc_columns 
    RefreshColumns=@RefreshColumns 
></MVCTableColumnManager>

<MVCTable 
    TItem=@SharedTestData 
    data=@data 
    visible_col_names=@visible_mvc_columns
></MVCTable>

@code {
    //prepare RenderFragments to display the data in every column of every row
    public static RenderFragment<SharedTestData> ValColId = 
        context  => 
            __builder =>{ <td scope="row" ><b>@context.id</b> </td>};
    public static RenderFragment<SharedTestData> ValColName = 
        context  => 
            __builder =>{ <td  >@context.name </td>};
    public static RenderFragment<SharedTestData> ValColDescription = 
        context  => 
            __builder =>{ <td style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap" >@context.description </td>};
    public static RenderFragment<SharedTestData> ValColExecutedOn = 
        context  => 
            __builder =>{ <td  >@context.executed_on.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") </td>};
    public static RenderFragment<SharedTestData> ValColExecutedBy = 
        context  => 
            __builder =>{ <td  >@context.executed_by </td>};
    public static RenderFragment<SharedTestData> ValColSuccess = 
        context  => 
                __builder =>{ <td class="text-center" >@( @context.success ?"☑":"☐")</td>};
    public static RenderFragment<SharedTestData> ValColErrorCF = 
        context  => 
            __builder =>{ <td class="text-end" >@context.error_CF </td>
    };
    //define all columns to be displayed in the table
    public MVCColumnCtrl<SharedTestData>[] mvc_columns = new MVCColumnCtrl<SharedTestData>[]
    {
        new MVCColumnCtrl<SharedTestData>("id" ,  ValColId , "#" ),
        new MVCColumnCtrl<SharedTestData>("name" , ValColName , "name" ),
        new MVCColumnCtrl<SharedTestData>("description" ,ValColDescription ) {visible = true},
        new MVCColumnCtrl<SharedTestData>("executed_on" ,ValColExecutedOn ){visible = true},
        new MVCColumnCtrl<SharedTestData>("executed_by" ,ValColExecutedBy ){visible = true},
        new MVCColumnCtrl<SharedTestData>("success" ,ValColSuccess ){visible = true},
        new MVCColumnCtrl<SharedTestData>("error_CF" ,ValColErrorCF ){visible = true}
    };
    //visible_mvc_columns will only contain mvc_columns where the visible property is set to true in the RefreshColumns method
    public static MVCColumnCtrl<SharedTestData>[] visible_mvc_columns = new MVCColumnCtrl<SharedTestData>[]
        {
        new MVCColumnCtrl<SharedTestData>("id" ,  ValColId , "#" ),
        new MVCColumnCtrl<SharedTestData>("name" , ValColName , "name" )
    };
    /// <summary>run at OnInitialized and pass to MVCTableColumnManager</summary>
    public void RefreshColumns()
    {
        visible_mvc_columns = mvc_columns.Where(col => col.visible == true).ToArray();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// sample dataset
    /// </summary>
    public SharedTestData[] data = new SharedTestData[]
    {
        new SharedTestData(){ id="ET220301", name="Efficiency", description="test for efficiency of program", executed_by="RX1",executed_on= DateTime.Now, error_CF= 0.31M, success=true },
        new SharedTestData(){ id="ET220302", name="Concurrency", description="test for ability to manage resources", executed_by="RX1",executed_on= DateTime.Now, error_CF= 0.21M, success=false },
        new SharedTestData(){ id="ET220303", name="Effability", description="test for ability eff with system", executed_by="RX1",executed_on= DateTime.Now, error_CF= 0M, success=false },
        new SharedTestData(){ id="ET220304", name="Edibility", description="test for edibility", executed_by="RX1",executed_on= DateTime.Now, error_CF= 0.8M, success=true },
        new SharedTestData(){ id="ET220305", name="Efficiency", description="test for efficiency of program", executed_by="RX2",executed_on= DateTime.Now, error_CF= 0.31M, success=true },
        new SharedTestData(){ id="ET220306", name="Concurrency", description="test for ability to manage resources", executed_by="RX2",executed_on= DateTime.Now, error_CF= 0.21M, success=false },
        new SharedTestData(){ id="ET220307", name="Effability", description="test for ability to eff with system", executed_by="RX2",executed_on= DateTime.Now, error_CF= 0M, success=false },
        new SharedTestData(){ id="ET220308", name="Edibility", description="test for edibility", executed_by="RX2",executed_on= DateTime.Now, error_CF= 0.8M, success=true }
    };
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        RefreshColumns();
    }
}
```

Comment: On the "Not Supported", anything you can do in a razor file, you can do in a class file.  Write a razor file, turn on `EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles` in the project and look at the class files produced by Razor pre-compiler.

Comment: Once you get your head around `RenderFragments` you'll use them more and more.  One comment, if you haven't already read it is don't be tempted to use an iterator for sequence numbering.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis thank you for the feedback, seems we are living slightly different timezones, sorry to keep you waiting. Do you mean the way I am reordering the columns in `MoveColUp` or the way I added a numbered column using `i`?  I kind of rushed that part.

Comment: NP.  I'm CET.  None of the above.  if you write a method using the builder to build out your markup - something like `Builder.OpenElement(0, "div")`, don't use an iterator to generate the sequence numbers you use.  See an example here on the AspNetCore Github Repo - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/08b9ded29ae8696fbbd1b5ae2f66b16739da4bef/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputText.cs#L32.

Comment: GMT+8 here , Understood, I was not yet planning to use the `RenderTreeBuilder` but thank you for the heads-up. Out of interest what happens if you do?

Comment: See this gist from one of the top MS Blazor people - https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/ec232992c2446ab9a0059dd0fbc5d0c3

Comment: An interesting read, thanks! :)